# How to exclude more than one file name ending with vsdx or avi?

Tags: javascript, rest

I'm able to grab the files, but haven't been successful excluding more than one file name ending with vsdx or avi.

I need to exclude more than one file type.

Any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
url: "https://gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Production_Library/communication management')/files?$select=LinkingURL,Name&$orderby=LinkingURL$filter=not endswith(Name,’vsdx’)",
type: "GET",
headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
cache:false,                
success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var html = "<table border='0'>";
        $(data.d.results).each(function(){
            html = html + "<a href='" + this.LinkingUrl + "' target='_blank' >" + this.Name + "</a><br/>" ;
        });
        html += "</table>";
        $("#listResult2").html(html)
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(data.d.results).each(function(){
var fileExt = this.Name.split('.').pop();
if (fileExt != "vsdx" && fileExt != "avi")
{
 html = html + "<a href='" + this.LinkingUrl + "' target='_blank' >" + this.Name + "</a><br/>" ;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To rephrase your question, you would like to filter files by file extensions. If so, then i would recommend to consider these options:

### About`endswith` function

According to [OData query operators supported in the SharePoint REST service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx) `endsWith` function is **not supported**

### Using `substringof` function

Since `endsWith` function is **not supported**, here is an  alternative solution that allows to filter files by extension.

The example demonstrates how to exclude files those names contains `.xslx` or `.docx`

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents')/files?$filter=not substringof('.docx',Name) and not substringof('.xslx',Name)
```

### Using CAML query

The following example  demonstrates how to filter *list items* by extension using CAML query:

```
function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle,folderUrl, viewXml) 
{
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml,
                      'FolderServerRelativeUrl': folderUrl
               }
    };

    return $.ajax({
           url: url,
           method: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
           headers: {
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
              "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
           }
     });
}
```

**Usage**

Example that returns list items under `Guides` folder from Documents library and excludes `.docx` & `.xslx` file types:

```
var query = '<View>' +
              '<Query>' + 
                 '<Where>' +
                    '<And><Neq><FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Type" /><Value Type="text">docx</Value></Neq><Neq><FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Type" /><Value Type="text">html</Value></Neq></And>' +
                 '</Where>' +
               '</Query>' +
             '</View>';
getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Documents','/Documents/Guides',query)
.done(function(data)
{
     var items = data.d.results;
     for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
         console.log(items[i].Title);
     }    
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```